# Programmatically Cancel SalesOrders in AX

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I would like to programmatically cancel all SalesOrders in AX2009 that have status of BackOrder and are less than a specific date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do this by running the following Job

```
static void SalesOrderUpdate(Args _args)
{
    SalesTable          salesTable;
    SalesLine           salesLine;
    int i;
    ;
    changecompany ('10')
    {
        ttsBegin;    
        while select forUpdate salesTable 
            where salesTable.SalesStatus == SalesStatus::Backorder
            &&    salesTable.ReceiptDateRequested  <= 31\12\2016
            &&    salesTable.ShippingDateRequested <= 31\12\2016
            join forUpdate salesLine
            where salesLine.SalesId == salesTable.SalesId
        {
            i++;    
            salesLine.RemainSalesPhysical = 0;
            salesLine.RemainInventPhysical = 0;
            salesLine.update();    
        }
        ttsCommit;    
    }
    info(int2Str(i));    
}
```

Comment: Oh, the tts shoud be outside the loop as well.

Comment: Wouldn't this increase memory usage by a lot?

Comment: Short answer: no. But lines may be locked for the duration of the update.